# Get request parameters by AWS request ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I got this log message:

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key
>   does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code:
>   NoSuchKey; Request ID: `request_id`; S3 Extended Request ID:`extended_request_id`)

Is it possible to get parameters for the request (in this case S3 key and bucket) by `request_id` and `extended_request_id` ?

Comment: I think it doesn't give you the request parameters from aws sdk. I think you can get the s3 key and bucket if you log the AWS request and responses by enabling the http debug log. Please refer to this: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-logging.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Request ID is received on the wire as `x-amz-request-id` and is styled as the `Request ID` in the [S3 access logs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html).

This will not provide exhaustive information about the request parameters, depending on what you are trying to find, but it will show the bucket and key -- though you'll have to know which bucket's logs to look in, of course.

More detailed information about the request can potentially found in [CloudTrail logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-cloudtrail-events.html). Object level requests are not captured by CloudTrail by default, so you'd need to enable this.  The request ID should appear [in these logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html) as well.

The Extended Request ID, also called `x-amz-id-2` is -- as far as I am aware -- only of use to AWS support when tracing things internally for you.  Neither value is known to contain sensitive information.  The extended ID may be a large random number or may be encrypted, but if it is encrypted, there is no documented way to decrypt it.  The documentation calls it a ["special token."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html)  A little bit more detail in the context of support is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/troubleshooting.html#get-request-ids).

In summary, there is no short/simple "lookup" method but it is possible, as noted above.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to CloudWatch Log Insights you can run a query:

```
fields @requestId, @message, @timestamp | filter @message like /\"requestID\":\"REQUEST_ID\"/
```

You may see suggestions of something like:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /REQUEST_ID/
```

This works but with continued testing it will start to fill up your search results with the searches you have done, so the first approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

As of starting may 2023, the below cloudwatch query is working for me

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter webaclId = "arn:aws:wafv2:us-east-1:829107270802:global/webacl/xxxxxxx/7ad609ef-bb73-356c-b93d-15faf5d79a43"
| filter httpRequest.requestId = "t9S3k2h6BS328NC36nRKkrMEOP7XNfdk62GnSen1quoxEiTahXoGHA=="
```

Just Replace your webaclID with your waf ID and the request ID you wish to look for.